# Foreach wrap only last elements

Tags: for-loop, foreach

I have a problem with foreach splitting. I need wrap with submenu only that items, that is more like 10 to get show more div.

How can I get to fully wrap all other items?

```
<ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Visas preces</a></li>
                    <?php
                    $childid =  get_product_top_level_category ( get_the_ID());  
                    $args = array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'parent' => $childid
                    );
                    $terms = get_terms( $args );
                    $i = 1;
                    foreach( $terms as $term ) { 
                        echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link( $term->slug, 'product_cat' ).'">'. $term->name .'</a></li>';
                        if ($i == 10)
                        { ?></li>
                           <li class="more dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Vairāk</a>

                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                               <ul>
                        <?php }
                        $i++;   
                    } 
                    ?>
                           </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add logic for all other index in an else case for the if $i == 10 if condition

```
if ($t < "20") {
    echo "Have a good day!";
} else {
    echo "Have a good night!";
}
```

Comment: Problem is for close tags.